# Group By 'Then' Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't seem to figure out how to make this report combine the two numbers for DRML. Right now it is giving me 5 rows when I need shelter and LSCC to be combined. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT SUM(service.ServiceTotal) as servTotal, 
CASE
WHEN ProgramName = 'Crossing Operations' THEN 'Crossing'
WHEN ProgramName = 'Shelter' or ProgramName = 'LSCC' THEN 'DRML'
WHEN ProgramName = 'Farm Operations' THEN 'Harvest Farm'
WHEN ProgramName = 'Champa Operations' THEN 'Champa'
ELSE ProgramName   
END
as ProgName,
ProgramName, CONVERT(date,service.BeginDate) as BeginDate
FROM dbo.Service
JOIN Enrollment on service.EnrollmentID = Enrollment.EnrollmentID
JOIN Program on Enrollment.ProgramID = program.ProgramID
WHERE dbo.service.ServiceTypeID IN (264,429,430,266,431,432,265,273,433,434,493,494,495,500,501,502,496,498,497,499, 270,436,462,435,272,438,463,437,271,460,441,461,442,267,446,448,447,445,443,444,459,269,457,458,456,454,455,268,452,453,451,449,450,514,
275,276,277) and service.DeletedDate > GETDATE() and DATEDIFF(day,Service.BeginDate, GETDATE()) = 1 --and service.ProvidedToEntityID = 161737
and Enrollment.programID IN (84,87,118,126,119,150)
GROUP BY ProgramName, CONVERT(date,service.BeginDate)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, service.BeginDate), ProgramName
```

Comment: Put the same case statement in your group by... or better will use a CTE to transform the input data and use a group by over that CTE.

Comment: Why are you selecting both `ProgramName` as is AND a `CASE` column from its values?

Answer (score 1):

Take `ProgramName` out of your `group by` and `select` list; and add your `case` expression to your `group by`; and change `ProgramName` to `ProgName` in your `order by`.

```
SELECT 
    servTotal = SUM(service.ServiceTotal) 
  , ProgName = CASE
      WHEN ProgramName = 'Crossing Operations' THEN 'Crossing'
      WHEN ProgramName = 'Shelter' or ProgramName = 'LSCC' THEN 'DRML'
      WHEN ProgramName = 'Farm Operations' THEN 'Harvest Farm'
      WHEN ProgramName = 'Champa Operations' THEN 'Champa'
      ELSE ProgramName   
      END
--, ProgramName
  , BeginDate = CONVERT(date,service.BeginDate) 
FROM dbo.Service
JOIN Enrollment on service.EnrollmentID = Enrollment.EnrollmentID
JOIN Program on Enrollment.ProgramID = program.ProgramID
WHERE dbo.service.ServiceTypeID IN (264,429,430,266,431,432,265,273,433,434,493,494,495,500,501,502,496,498,497,499, 270,436,462,435,272,438,463,437,271,460,441,461,442,267,446,448,447,445,443,444,459,269,457,458,456,454,455,268,452,453,451,449,450,514,
275,276,277) and service.DeletedDate > GETDATE() and DATEDIFF(day,Service.BeginDate, GETDATE()) = 1 --and service.ProvidedToEntityID = 161737
and Enrollment.programID IN (84,87,118,126,119,150)
GROUP BY 
  --ProgramName
  CASE
    WHEN ProgramName = 'Crossing Operations' THEN 'Crossing'
    WHEN ProgramName = 'Shelter' or ProgramName = 'LSCC' THEN 'DRML'
    WHEN ProgramName = 'Farm Operations' THEN 'Harvest Farm'
    WHEN ProgramName = 'Champa Operations' THEN 'Champa'
    ELSE ProgramName   
  END
  , CONVERT(date,service.BeginDate)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, service.BeginDate), ProgName
```

Comment: I tried that and it says that Column "Program.ProgramName" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Ashley Change `ProgramName` to `ProgName` in your `order by`

Answer (score 1):

You need to `GROUP BY` your `CASE` expression instead of `ProgramName`:

```
SELECT  SUM(s.ServiceTotal) servTotal, 
        CASE
            WHEN ProgramName = 'Crossing Operations' THEN 'Crossing'
            WHEN ProgramName IN ('Shelter','LSCC') THEN 'DRML'
            WHEN ProgramName = 'Farm Operations' THEN 'Harvest Farm'
            WHEN ProgramName = 'Champa Operations' THEN 'Champa'
            ELSE ProgramName   
        END ProgName,
        CONVERT(date,s.BeginDate) BeginDate
FROM dbo.Service s
INNER JOIN Enrollment e
    ON s.EnrollmentID = e.EnrollmentID
INNER JOIN Program p 
    ON e.ProgramID = p.ProgramID
WHERE s.ServiceTypeID IN (264,429,430,266,431,432,265,273,433,434,493,494,495,500,
501,502,496,498,497,499, 270,436,462,435,272,438,463,437,271,460,441,461,442,267,
446,448,447,445,443,444,459,269,457,458,456,454,455,268,452,453,451,449,450,514,
275,276,277) 
AND s.DeletedDate > GETDATE() AND DATEDIFF(DAY,s.BeginDate, GETDATE()) = 1 --and service.ProvidedToEntityID = 161737
AND Enrollment.programID IN (84,87,118,126,119,150)
GROUP BY CASE
            WHEN ProgramName = 'Crossing Operations' THEN 'Crossing'
            WHEN ProgramName IN ('Shelter','LSCC') THEN 'DRML'
            WHEN ProgramName = 'Farm Operations' THEN 'Harvest Farm'
            WHEN ProgramName = 'Champa Operations' THEN 'Champa'
            ELSE ProgramName   
         END,
         CONVERT(date,service.BeginDate)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, service.BeginDate), 
         CASE
            WHEN ProgramName = 'Crossing Operations' THEN 'Crossing'
            WHEN ProgramName IN ('Shelter','LSCC') THEN 'DRML'
            WHEN ProgramName = 'Farm Operations' THEN 'Harvest Farm'
            WHEN ProgramName = 'Champa Operations' THEN 'Champa'
            ELSE ProgramName   
         END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are `GROUPING BY` all the different values of the `ProgramName` column directly, not by the `CASE` values you are specifying.

First select all the values in a subquery or a CTE and then select the `SUM` over those results.

```
SELECT SUM(service.ServiceTotal) as servTotal, ProgName, BeginDate
FROM(
    SELECT service.ServiceTotal, 
    CASE
    WHEN ProgramName = 'Crossing Operations' THEN 'Crossing'
    WHEN ProgramName = 'Shelter' or ProgramName = 'LSCC' THEN 'DRML'
    WHEN ProgramName = 'Farm Operations' THEN 'Harvest Farm'
    WHEN ProgramName = 'Champa Operations' THEN 'Champa'
    ELSE ProgramName   
    END
    as ProgName,
    CONVERT(date,service.BeginDate) as BeginDate
    FROM dbo.Service
    JOIN Enrollment on service.EnrollmentID = Enrollment.EnrollmentID
    JOIN Program on Enrollment.ProgramID = program.ProgramID
    WHERE dbo.service.ServiceTypeID IN (264,429,430,266,431,432,265,273,433,434,493,494,495,500,501,502,496,498,497,499, 270,436,462,435,272,438,463,437,271,460,441,461,442,267,446,448,447,445,443,444,459,269,457,458,456,454,455,268,452,453,451,449,450,514,
    275,276,277) and service.DeletedDate > GETDATE() and DATEDIFF(day,Service.BeginDate, GETDATE()) = 1 --and service.ProvidedToEntityID = 161737
    and Enrollment.programID IN (84,87,118,126,119,150)) AS t
GROUP BY ProgName, BeginDate
ORDER BY BeginDate, ProgName
```

or

```
WITH cte(ServiceTotal, ProgName, BeginDate) AS
(
    SELECT service.ServiceTotal, 
    CASE
    WHEN ProgramName = 'Crossing Operations' THEN 'Crossing'
    WHEN ProgramName = 'Shelter' or ProgramName = 'LSCC' THEN 'DRML'
    WHEN ProgramName = 'Farm Operations' THEN 'Harvest Farm'
    WHEN ProgramName = 'Champa Operations' THEN 'Champa'
    ELSE ProgramName   
    END
    as ProgName,
    CONVERT(date,service.BeginDate) as BeginDate
    FROM dbo.Service
    JOIN Enrollment on service.EnrollmentID = Enrollment.EnrollmentID
    JOIN Program on Enrollment.ProgramID = program.ProgramID
    WHERE dbo.service.ServiceTypeID IN (264,429,430,266,431,432,265,273,433,434,493,494,495,500,501,502,496,498,497,499, 270,436,462,435,272,438,463,437,271,460,441,461,442,267,446,448,447,445,443,444,459,269,457,458,456,454,455,268,452,453,451,449,450,514,
    275,276,277) and service.DeletedDate > GETDATE() and DATEDIFF(day,Service.BeginDate, GETDATE()) = 1 --and service.ProvidedToEntityID = 161737
    and Enrollment.programID IN (84,87,118,126,119,150)
)

SELECT SUM(service.ServiceTotal) as servTotal, ProgName, BeginDate
FROM cte
GROUP BY ProgName, BeginDate
ORDER BY BeginDate, ProgName
```